# Circle equations that include tangent line

Tags: circles

It's a system like this
$$\begin{cases} x^2+y^2=25\\ y=x-2\end{cases}$$
and then says "solve it"
I have no idea what to do please help me.

Comment: The second equation allows you to plug $(x-2)$ instead of $y$ in the first one. Then you get a quadratic equation with one variable to solve.

Comment: "I have no idea what to do": solve it.

Comment: Why do you think the line is a tangent...?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Write
$$x^2+(x-2)^2=25.$$